# jQuery Mobile refreshing a div for web mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, refresh

How can I refresh a div in jqm? My problem is I have a div(#menu) on a toggle to show/hide. This works fine but when I navigate through pages the toggle script gets disabled. I have to refresh the page it's on or disable ajax for all pages.

I have read through posts with similar issues and tried the solutions like listview('refresh') but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code. Many thanks.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">

<div data-role="header">
<h1>Page 1</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">

<!-- TOGGLE --> 
<div data-role="navbar" data-grid="a" id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Items</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- /TOGGLE --> 

<a href="#" data-role="button" id="nav">open menu</a>

</div>

<div data-role="footer">
footer content
</div>

<script>
$('#nav').click(function() {
$('#menu').toggle(); 
});
</script>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried delegating the event with `.on("click", function(){})` instead of `.click(function(){})`?

Comment: Just gave that a go and still disabled when navigating to another page.

Comment: All of your events are done through AJAX? If so, it's hacky but you can throw this into your callbacks on those events: `$("#nav").unbind("click").on("click", function(){ .... })`. That should clear it of all click events and then re-bind it to your nav.

Comment: Thanks for your help but that didn't seem to work either. I guess i could just apply a different id to the click function for each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `classes` instead of `ids`:

```
$('.nav').click(function() {
  $('.menu').toggle(); 
});
```

and put the `<script>..</script>` **after** the last `</div>` http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/CuGkW/1/